# How can I make my PHP script run at a certain time everyday?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that checks my database's code for validity. How can I have this run everyday at a certain time so then I can just have it run on autopilot.

Comment: I'm curious: how can your database's code become suddenly invalid?

Comment: @marcog not really conjob is the ANSWER not the question.

Comment: Alvaro, its user inputted. I do the check as a mass instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you want is called a cron job and is already covered here:

[PHP: running scheduled jobs (cron jobs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs)

Answer (score 8):

If you are using **cPanel** on your host, you can go to Advanced --> cron jobs.
Then inside there you can set a cron job command like this:

```
wget http://yoursite.com/yourfile.php
```

which `http://yoursite.com/yourfile.php` should point to your desired function.
You can also set repetition time interval over there.

This way `yourfile.php` is called in specified intervals.

Comment: Is it possible to point to several files in the directory?

Answer (score 3):

CronJobs feature are often disabled on most free or cheap Linux hosting. If you could use cron you could use that.

Alternatives:

- Use services like : http://www.setcronjob.com/ (many exist, just search on google) , to schedule your task for free(1x per hour).
- If you need a little bit more juice you should look into google app engine [cron](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html). In the cron you just do a simple [asynchronous request](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html) to call your page.

Answer (score 1):

There's a cli interpreter called `php`. Run your script through that as a [cron job](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

If you are a linux/unix user, i recommend you use [CRON](http://troy.jdmz.net/cron/) .

Answer (score 0):

May it will helps you.

You can schedule a task in Windows - control panel->administrative tools is where you find task scheduler.

[run a php automatically after every hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247167/run-a-php-automatically-after-every-hour)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have your own server you can run a cronjob(unix/linux) or a scheduled task(windows).

If your app/site is hosted on a shared host that does not offer cronjobs you an use a sevice like
http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/

I have not tested this one but If you google a bit(fee conjobs) you will find plenty of those.
They will call a certain a url accoding to a fixed schedule. Most of those sevices have a fixed set of ip addeses so you can pevent the scipt from being called by anyone else.

Comment: Windows Scheduler sucks. Its not reliable at all and does not run at the exact same time requested.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily use your database to save the last execution of the script.

Each execution of a certain page you run a script that does the following :

- Check if more than 8 hours (example)
- Checks in the database if the script has already been executed

If executed: does nothing.

If not executed: starts and updates the date last execution in database.