# How to run php script at 12am everyday

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: running scheduled jobs (cron jobs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs)
>   [How can I make my PHP script run at a certain time everyday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558601/how-can-i-make-my-php-script-run-at-a-certain-time-everyday)

I basically need a way to run a script that's going to check if someone has attended an event and at 12am, add the event to a user's events table. I can get that part no problem. I just need it to run every day at the end of the day or first thing in the morning (12am). It's going to be a php script. How can I make this run everyday at 12am?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the host you're running on and it's a UNIX-like machine, using `cron` would be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a scheduler to run the script for you at the specified time. For example, if you're on Linux, you could use cron. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1):

Make a cron job/scheduled task and start the php cli like "php.exe myscript.php" at 12am.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is a cron job. If you're on shared hosting, this is usually available by going to cPanel and selecting "Cron tasks" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

See [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash script and run it as a cronjob