# run a php automatically after every hour

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I am using a shared windows hosting in which sending 120 mails/hour is allowed though php code.
i have a php page to send emails more than 200 mails at a time.But i want to run the page, after every hour(scheduled task). 
I will split the emails(in 100s) and want send automatically after every hour.

How is this possible in php to run a php page after every hour ?

Thanks

Comment: cronjob or what ever the windows equivalent is. why would would you ever host on windows?

Comment: You can set this up using Plesk - at least that's what I'm presuming you're using because that seems to be the only major panel that actively supports a separate build for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a task in Windows - control panel->administrative tools is where you find task scheduler.

Answer (score 8):

Use PHP Cron Jobs with cPanel

cPanel Simple Cron

you can get started with the simple cron tool built into cPanel. The url for it is:

https://www.yoursite.com/page.php

The command to run:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/(username)/public_html/page.php
```

Next you'll want to select an option from all the select boxes. Remember to select an option in each box. If you want something to run every hour, select Minute: 60; Hour:Every; Day: Every; Month: Every; Weekday: Every;

Click save and you are all set! You'll get an email every time the cron job runs, but if you don't want to get it - put :blackhole: into the output email field at the top.

Comment: Even though you answered the wrong question, I found this solution very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use a script on Google AppEngine to "ping" yours ([Scheduled Tasks](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) to be more precise). 
It's free to use.