# Calling PHP pages automatically?

Tags: php, sql, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: running scheduled jobs (cron jobs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs)

I need to update a database every 20 mins lets say. (ie. add 50 to 'X' column, subtract 20 form 'y' column, preform an equation based on time on 'z' column, etc.) I have the necessary update in a update.php page but how would i go about calling that page every 20 minutes (short of scheduling a task on a computer)? or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Linux

This should be done as a [cron job](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) or alternatively [using `at` to](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at) schedule the job. I have written a PHP wrapper for the `at` command that you could use for this purpose: https://github.com/treffynnon/PHP-at-Job-Queue-Wrapper

### Windows

You need to use [Scheduled Tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569). Here is a link to an old article I wrote about moving Linux cronjobs to a Windows machine: http://blog.simonholywell.com/post/374209271/linux-to-windows-server-migrating-and-securing-your-cron

Comment: Argh, Problem is it's being hosted on a Hostmonster DB. no way's around this, eh?

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like this service to work around the problem: http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/ or you could possible use Google App Engine as I think it has scheduled tasks now.

Answer (score 2):

Where does this page live? If it's on a Linux box, use a cron job. If it's on a Windows machine, use a Scheduled Task.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no, you're going to have to schedule a task. Basically because this situation is exactly what it is made for!

On Linux you can use a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). On windows it is done with a [scheduled task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)