# Run PHP file at scheduled times?

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I have a php file which pulls some data from external API's, and I want to schedule it to do so every few hours (or every few days). Some googleing led me to "scheduled tasks", but it seems I need to be running my own server to do it?

So far, all the PHP and MySQL I've done have been very simple form-filling, so I'm a little lost. Do I need to turn a computer into a server to do this, or should I look into hosts that allow you to run scripts? I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for.

Side-question: how would I be able to prevent someone else from running the PHP script (therefor making tons of API calls)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs. For your side question, require a secret query parameter to be present for the script to run.

Comment: What version of windows are you using and when is your machine typically turned on?

Comment: I'm using a mac, but I also have a windows 7 desktop. the mac is a laptop so it varies, the desktop is hardly used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you running the script now? Windows or Linux? Linux is a no-brainer with cron: on a PHP-enabled server simply drop the PHP script somewhere, edit the crontab and away you go!

Ex. for every 2 hours

```
0 */2 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.php
```

Edit Re: Mac

[launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) is apparently the preferred method to run scheduled tasks but I understand that OS X has cron capabilities as well being a UNIX derivative.

Comment: on a mac, just navigating to the local file in my browser while running XAMPP (apache, mysql, ftp)

Comment: Mac runs BSD, so a cronjob will work. The php path maybe different, so just find out that bit and you are good to go.

Comment: Don't forget the often forgotten and lonely `at` and `batch` commands in *nix.

Answer (score 1):

cronjobs are made for it... You can check the Cron Jobs in cpanel.. 
I am assuming your website is launched in Linu environment

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

http://man.cx/cron

You can find much more exlaination about the Background Process

http://www.fijiwebdesign.com/blog/create-a-background-process-on-the-server-with-php.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reasonably busy web server, you can simply check every time how long it has been since the last time you ran the script. If more than two hours, run it.

Just make sure to update the time and run the script atomically so you don't launch several copies of the script. You can do this with a file that contains the last time the script was run that you *lock* while you check and update it.