# Invoking a PHP function from a MySQL trigger

Tags: php

I want to call a Php function using the MYsqli trigger and I have found that this has a lot of security threat. I want to send an sms daily at certain time to all those in my database who's license expiry is within 7 days so what should be my approach to this?

Comment: Get the list of users and simply throw a `cron` instead of invoking it from MySQL trigger

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004710/run-php-file-at-scheduled-times or http://stackoverflow.com/a/9122112/5612089

Comment: use cronjob to execute a php file at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to do by cron .its my suggestion

This is the best explanation with code in PHP I have found so far:[reference](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)

**cron.php**

```
        <?php

          echo "hiiii";
          Do ur stuff here ....
        ?>
```

You can edit the crontab usually (not always the case) by entering crontab -e in a ssh session on the server.

```
        every minute 

        */1 * * * * php /var/www/path/to/cron.php
```

Above code execute the cron.php every seconds once.customize by your need

The stars represent (* means every of this unit):

```
        [Minute] [Hour] [Day] [Month] [Day of week (0 =sunday to 6 =saturday)] [Command]
```

Comment: I am currently running my php and mysql in my windows system(Localhost) can this be done in windows also?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894804/use-php-to-set-cron-jobs-in-windows

Comment: Thanks jothi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894804/use-php-to-set-cron-jobs-in-windows this worked