# how i can running php code in identified time.( for example clock 1:00)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: running scheduled jobs (cron jobs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs)
>   [How to run a PHP file in a scheduled task (Windows Task Scheduler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task-windows-task-scheduler)

i want execute php code in 1:00 clock in every day .   Scorsese i know php running when web page viewed .
for example i want update field of my database in Specified time (e.g 1:00 clock).
there is way or not ?
thanks .

Comment: What is your os? If unix-like, use cron to execute your script at specified times (http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/cron/).

Comment: @aya: in that case use Windows Task Scheduler

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you could try with things like this one :

http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

Is for do one daemon with php and later configure it as you want. Other possibility is crontab and with it execute one file each 1m,2m,...( execute contrab -e for edit it and crontab -l for see it )  :

```
*/1  * * * * /usr/bin/php /Users/rfanjul/Public/inversia/app/console twitter:hashtags:get
```

the last option is create one bash file like this one:

```
tiempo="10s"
comando="sensors"
fich_salida="temperatura.txt"
while [ true ]; do
sleep $tiempo
echo ///////////////////////// >> $fich_salida
echo ///////////////////////// >> $fich_salida
date >> $fich_salida  
echo ///////////////////////// >> $fich_salida
$comando >> $fich_salida
echo ///////////////////////// >> $fich_salida
done
```

For you i think that the better solution is crontab with this configuration:

```
* 1 * * * file
```