# i want to run the following php script continously in specified intervals of time and can be set by a user using a form. how to do this?

Tags: php

//i need to run this script repetadly and the time interval can be set by a user

// checking the internet connection

```
if (!$sock = fsockopen("www.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr,20))
    {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

alert("Connection problem");

</script>

<?php       
    }
```

// retriving data from database and checking the site is down

```
else
    {
    for($i=0;$i<count($res);$i++)
        {
        $fp=fsockopen($res[$i]['url'],80,$errno,$errstr,30);
        if($fp==false)
            {
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 alert("Website is down");

 </script>

 <?php
```

// writing data to database and sending mail

```
mail($email[0]['email_id'],"website is down",$res[$i]['url']." is down");
    $inputs=array('website_id'=>$res[$i['website_id'],
    'date'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),'reason'=>"website down");
$obj3->addLog($inputs);
         }
    }
}
sleep(300);
}
```

Comment: did you even try to lookup up to how run timed jobs? We're not a search engine.

Comment: Try to explain the question in the body instead of the title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: running scheduled jobs (cron jobs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with cron is this `"and the time interval can be set by a user"`.

You can use `cron` such way, that you run script every 30 seconds or every N seconds. That is your **smallest granularity** for running script.

Now, if user sets that script must be run every 30 minutes, first thing you do at script is check that, if script needs to proceed - if last run was before that 30 minutes that user set. Script pseudo goes like this:

```
1) load last run from DB, compare it with interval - do we need to proceed, if not exit
2) do what script needs to do
3) save to the DB last run time
```

Of course this all is only necessary, if user needs to be able to **dynamically change run interval** and dont want to touch cron.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `cron` service. Someone has already explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120228/1056693).

If you want it to stay in the form of a web page, automatically reloading itself, then look at the JavaScript function `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. First, you can use [cron jobs](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) to automatically run a script at a set time. Your javascript won't work as the PHP script will be running directly on the server and you won't be able to show anything in a browser.

If you want the user to have the page open while it's doing all of this so the script can report data on the screen, I would just set the time in the URL as GET parameters `mypage.php?refreshTime=1800` and then read it using `$_GET['refreshTime']` and then use the following line to set the refresh time.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="$refreshTime">
```

This will cause the page to reload after `$refreshTime` seconds. Your PHP to do whatever it is it needs to do will run on each refresh as it does now when you load the page.

Comment: how to run a php script continously when the system is on without usng cron, because i need to set the refreshing interval dynamicaly??? can anyone suggest a method..

Comment: I did in the second part of my answer. Should I elaborate on it? What don't you understand exactly?