# MySQL autoincrement by day?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I decrement a MySQL field every day?

Such as:

field1= 30 and after 24hours -> field1=29  until 0.

Comment: What do you actually need this for? I have a feeling you'd be much better off just calculating the value when you need it, without needing to decrement it in "realtime".

Comment: What is the purpose of this functionality? Something tells me that your solution to a problem is more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably be better off placing the current date in the database, and then use [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to get the days since. You could even do 30 - DATEDIFF and then have the number the way you want it.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a Unix *cron job* (there's some informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs)) which will execute your PHP script every day.