# Possible to run a symfony task at a certain time of the day automatically?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, scheduled-tasks

I have tasks that I can run through the command line manually, but what if I wanted it to run automatically, once a day, at noon. Can that be done with symfony or would an external process have to be used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: running scheduled jobs (cron jobs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use your system's cron task scheduler. If you're on a shared hosting account with CPanel you can easily set that up via that interface. Otherwise, you might want to look at the following website: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use [`cron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) which would make your crontab look something like

```
0 12 * * * /path/to/project/symfony namespace:task arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

If the subject is a single job, windows task scheduler or cron for ux is enough. But if the things become more complex, you should better look for a job scheduler.