# PHP checking a value every 5 seconds without a present client

Tags: php, ajax

I have a website idea at the moment and I need a timer to be fired every 5 seconds without the users input to check if a remote value (a value on a remote file) has changed to a certain value.
Would I need to make a server side C++ script for this? I want to keep it all PHP if I can but  if I have to I will make an external script. Would AJAX be able to do this?

Comment: I want this all without a browser being present at all.

Comment: I love how you want to use AJAX *'without a browser present at all'*. Also, your title says 5 seconds and the text 5 minutes. Which is it?

Comment: @Niels The interval doesnt matter. I didnt really mean AJAX exclusively, I just ment is there a way to achieve this in an AJAX fashion.

Comment: Right, now that you edited 5 minutes to 5 seconds all previous answers are invalid. Crons can't run that frequently.

Comment: The interval most certainly matters. The standardized way of frequently executing recurring jobs, the `cronjob`, has a maximum frequency of once per minute.

Comment: I'd reverse the logic. Have the web server request an external URL when it sees that a value has changed to a certain value. Instead of hammering the server every 5 seconds when nothing has changed.

Comment: Ahh ok. Yeah its a 5 second refresh interval. cronjob looks like the only option from this point forward.

Comment: I'm downvoting this topic as 'unclear' since it has become a mess with all the previous answers suggesting cronjobs, which cannot run that frequently. I'd recommend you delete it and start over with a new topic that is *correct* and *complete* to begin with.

Comment: I cant delete it because there are answers. I apologise for my in-complete thread. Been really tired today.

Comment: Well in advance of the new topic - the only way I see this happening is by creating a `cron` that runs a PHP script every minute, that launches a fire&forget call on another PHP script every 5 seconds, 12 times, before quitting. That should get you close enough to executing the code every 5 seconds. Won't make your hosting provider happy though.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Cron` ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron ) for unix based systems and `Windows Task Scheduler` ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569 ) for windows

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a [cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs), sort of like:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/my/script.php
```

Or use remote invocation if you set the script to be callable from the outside as well:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/wget -s http://external.url/to/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it 5 minutes or 5 seconds?  Either way, your question is a bit confusing since you say "without persistent client," so does that mean without any connection from a client?  In that case it sounds like a responsibility for a cron job.  If your goal is to have a client request this value from your server periodically, then ajax is the simplest solution although websockets may also be viable.  You can do this with any server technology with any scripting language on the server side.  It's certainly possible with apache+PHP.