# How to setup cron script in moodle through plugin

Tags: php, cron, moodle

I want to run my cron script at sheduled intervels created at blocks/plugin_name/cron.php . Please help me how to create and call this cron script to run at regular intervels.

Comment: https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Cron

Comment: sorry i gone through those docs can any one explain brefily how to create and call cron script from blocks/plugin_name/cron.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: running scheduled jobs (cron jobs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the question is related to Moodle's use of cron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cron.php is the old way, you should create a `function plugin_name_cron()` in `blocks/plugin_name/lib.php`

Then in version.php you have a cron parameter which will tell Moodle to run the plugin every x seconds.

```
$plugin->cron = 0; // Seconds.
```

So every 15 minutes is

```
$plugin->cron = 15*60; // Seconds.
```

0 seconds means never run the cron.

This does depend on the admin cron being run too. If the admin cron is run ever 60 minutes then your plugin cron will only be run every 60 minutes.

For testing you can run the admin cron manually from http://yoursite.com/admin/cron.php

If you want to schedule the cron to run at a certain time, then you will need to add some code to your cron function to work out the scheduled time.

EDIT:

Actually the cron function is slightly different for blocks. Create a `function cron()` in your class `class block_plugin_name extends block_base..`

UPDATE:

From Moodle 2.7+, the above has been replaced with scheduled tasks https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Task_API#Scheduled_task_usage

Comment: i created lib.php as  <?php
function mailer_cron() {
    global $CFG, $DB;
 $t=time();
$record->userid         = 2;
$record->courseid = 101;
$record->coursestarttime = $t;
$record->courseendtime = $t;
$record->duefreq = $t;
$lastinsertid = $DB->insert_record('due_freq_details', $record, false);
} and in verison i added plugin->cron=15*60; but db is not updated

Comment: If you have a look at my edit comment - its slightly different for blocks

Comment: can i insert above code in function corn() in class block_plugin_name extends block_base..

Comment: its working when iam running http://yoursite.com/admin/cron.php.its not working for every specific time. i written an code to insert records in db in cron method but its not updating for every time mentioned in version.php.I kept $plugin->cron= 1*60; .I checked db after 1min without running http://yoursite.com/admin/cron.php file its ideal. please help in it.