# How to create new csv file for every 1 hour in php?

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to create a new csv for every hour based some updated data.

E.g If my first csv is generated at 10:00AM on 30 Jan,2019 then my csv file name would be "registered_employee_10_00_30-01-2019.csv".

Then, at 11:00 AM, on 30 Jan,2019 i.e after exactly one hour I want to create a new CSV file with name "registered_employee_11_00_30-01-2019.csv".

**So there will be two files in my directory.**

**1) "registered_employee_10_00_30-01-2019.csv".**

**2) "registered_employee_11_00_30-01-2019.csv".**

Basically, I want to create the new csv file for every hour.

What should be the php logic for this?

Comment: What you've tried so far ?

Comment: What you want has everything related to cron jobs and it is covered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a Cron Job to run every 1 hour in you SO:

Type the following in the linux terminal

`crontab -e`

And add the follow code (replace path/to/cron.php with you script):

`0 * * * * /usr/bin/php path/to/cron.php &> /dev/null`

It will run your script every 1 hour.

I hope it helps, regards.-

Comment: thanks juan .. for cron job... i have just searched... there are many formats where we can set cron for different scenarios